# How to compile xbindkeys

Tags: x11, compiling

I cloned the git repository of `xbindkeys` using:

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/xbindkeys.git
```

I want to compile it. How can I do this? Where can I find the compile instructions?

What are the dependencies?

Comment: Wasn't it available in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @slm It was. But I want to modify the code forking it for a personal project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading it when I run the `./configure` command it complained about 2 libraries missing:

```
checking for XCreateWindow in -lX11... no
configure: WARNING: Xbindkeys depends on the X11 libraries!
checking for guile... no
configure: error: guile required but not found
```

I had to install these 2 packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install guile-1.8-dev tk-dev
```

Afterwards a typical `./configure` and `make` worked fine.